# How to enable local mode of Fabric Composer Playground?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I installed Fabric Composer Playground based on this tutorial on Ubuntu 14.

> Installing and running the Fabric Composer Playground
>
> https://fabric-composer.github.io/tutorials/getting-started-playground.html

After the procedure, required docker container are running.

```
htanaka@ubuntu:~$ docker-compose ps
          Name                       Command                      State                       Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
htanaka_composer_1          pm2-docker composer-        Up                          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
                            playground
htanaka_membersrvc_1        membersrvc                  Up                          0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp
htanaka_vp0_1               sh -c sleep 5; peer node    Up                          0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp,
                            start                                                   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp,
                                                                                    0.0.0.0:7052->7052/tcp,
                                                                                    0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp
```

Everything looks OK, I can open "http:localhost:8080" and see playground pages. But When I open connection profile page, it says ...

> Connection Profiles are not available in Web Playground
>
> it is not possible to add Connection Profiles in the Web Playground
>   version of Fabric Composer
>   ...

How can I switch playground to local mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on adding support for connection profiles to the Composer Playground, and hope to be able to commit the code soon.

In the mean time you can use the old Composer-UI component.

Comment: How can I install a previous version? Do I have to modify the "docker-compose.yml" file I downloaded from the Getting Started?

Comment: Nevermind, I did it. I had to change the image (line 34) to "image: fabriccomposer/composer-ui"

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried composer-ui as Ma66oTo mentioned, and now I can change connection profile !